# html/jQuery to have no page refresh on form?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I've done some searching and I can't seem to find something like I need. Let me explain:

I've got a page that sends a get request to a db and then returns some question and answer data. I want the user to then be able to answer questions in a form without the page refreshing and losing the data that they have retrieved.

I have something working 'kind of' like I want. The problem with mine is that it is not in a form, it is just  and . This way the user would have to click on the input field and then click submit on the button every time.

I would prefer it if they could more or less just type and hit enter > see the next question > type and hit enter > etc.

Here is an example of what I have so far for reference...

```
<div id='content'>
    <div id='quizdiv'>
        <center>
            <button id='startbutton'>Click to load the data</button>
            <br><br>
            <!-- The actual quiz form, is hidden until the start button is clicked -->
                <div id='question' style='height: 40px; width: 250px; background-color: grey; border-radius:10%; font-weight:bold;'></div>
                <input type='text' id='answer'><br>
                <button id='answerbutton'>Check</button><br>
                <div id='result'></div>
        </center>
    </div>
```

**Javascript code:-**

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#startbutton').click(function() {
                    $.get('getquestion',
                          function(data, status) {

                            //gets the data from the view function in a large string 
                            var qAndA = data;
                            //turns the string data into jquery object
                            window.jsonQA = jQuery.parseJSON( qAndA );
                            //printing it for accuracy
                            console.log(jsonQA);
                            //pushes everything into an array so I can get a random element by index
                            window.questionArray = [];
                            for (var i in jsonQA) {
                                questionArray.push(i);
                            }
                            //generates a random index number based on the length
                            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * questionArray.length);
                            //create global var that is the random index from the question array
                            window.theQuestion = questionArray[index];
                            //changes the question div html to the question
                            $('#question').html(theQuestion);

                    });
                })
                $('#answerbutton').click(function() {
                    if ($('#answer').val() === jsonQA[theQuestion]) {
                        //prints right to the console
                        $('#result').html('CORRECT');
                    } else {
                        //prints wrong to the console
                        $('#result').html('WRONG');
                    }
                    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * questionArray.length)
                    window.theQuestion = questionArray[index]
                    $('#question').html(theQuestion);
                })

            })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just answered my own question. I was thinking about the problem the wrong way. Since I am not doing any sort of request, there is no reason to do anything in a form.

I have the data already loaded using ajax, so I can just take advantage of the ajax .keypress to do something on the page when the enter key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about AJAX. AJAX is a strategy to make requests to the server without reloading the page.

AJAX is not a new programming language, but a new way to use existing standards.

AJAX is the art of exchanging data with a server, and updating parts of a web page - without reloading the whole page.

Comment: yes I know, I believe I used ajax in there to accomplish what I have already. The problem is I need something that will not talk with the server, but only use information that has already been retrieved from the server using ajax